# Counting element height in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have such a Javascript code:

```
$content.each(function(i) {
    var $el = $(this);
    // save each content's height (where the menu items are)
    // and hide them by setting the height to 0px
    $el.data('height', $el.outerHeight(true)).css('height', '0px').show();
});
```

In such a situation:

```
 <div id="sbi_container" class="sbi_container">
        <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/1.jpg">
            <a href="#" class="sbi_label">About</a>
            <div class="sbi_content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/2.jpg">
            ...
        </div>
```

I don't know why, but when only an `<ul>` (which height we are counting) have a `<li>` with more than a one word in it, it adds a separate space below `<ul>`.
When there is only one long word, everything is ok.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: You need to increase `width` of your `ul` element

Comment: @Blaster shouldn't this increase by itself if no explicit width is set?

Comment: @JonTaylor: We don't know if it has no explicit width set, even if not, its width will then depend on its container

Comment: @Blaster I agree, however, the fact that one long word has a different behaviour is odd.  Although could be due to word wrap.  It would be good if the OP could provide some more detail.

Comment: I am using this one as fundament http://tympanus.net/Development/SlidingBackgroundImageMenu/example5.html.

And I am talking about submenu height.

I don't know Javascript very well, so what I can do is post entire code.. Because I don't know what do excactly you need to see to help me.

Say if I need to do this. :)

Thank you! :)

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/03/sliding-background-image-menu/

Here you can download the source.. The script, which I have problem with is in \js\jquery.bgImageMenu.js. line 29.

Comment: Could you please provide the simplest html code accompanying this JS code which produces the issue? So that we can have a look at it? Also: have you tested it with different browsers? Does it happen in every of them?

Comment: Yes, it happens in all browsers. Edited main post. There is a html code now, when such an issue happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.your_ul { font-size: 0; }
.your_ul li { font-size: 1234px }
```

it might work.